# Word for flexing/moving body part

Tags: word-usage, word-request

When you flex your hand to show the movement it has.

I also remember someone using this term for how someone could arrange their face when they show facial expressions.

E.g i articulated my foot to show the Doctor the movement i had.

Comment: The ones you listed, "flex" and "move", are pretty good choices.  Check out "tense" and "extend", although they are different.   Also... it is unclear exactly what the question is.  Are you looking for one single word that applies to all possible body parts, including the face?  Such a word might not exist.

Comment: Is articulate a suitable word?

Comment: That's an unusual choice. In context it makes sense. But I checked a few dictionaries that did not have that usage of articulate, so it's very uncommon at best, or not right, at worst.

Comment: articulate is not a verb except for a type of speech. He articulated his interest in geography.

Comment: If you are really talking to a health care professional then you might need the technical terms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_motion For your foot I imagine you either _flexed_ or _extended_ it.

Comment: Like your post.  Can you turn it into a question that can be answered?

Comment: With feet, this concerns the toes and the ankle.

Comment: I'd go for "wriggled".  That sounds a little bit colloquial and a little bit humorous, though, so if I wanted to avoid either of those things I'd go for "flexed".

Answer (score 1):

**For a foot, we are talking about the toes and the ankle.**

**The verbs are different for those.**

You can flex your whole foot, which involves moving the ankle, without moving your toes.

You wiggle or move or bend your toes and flex your ankle or rotate it.

No single verb applies to both.

Comment: In technical vocabulary you can either flex or extend your toe. You can also do the same for your foot but that has additional degrees of freedom involving rotation. However I am not sure whether technical vocab is allowed here.

Comment: @mdewey That is not only technical. And excuse me, but with all my foot troubles, I have never used or seen "extend" a toe. You can stretch out your toes. You extend an arm or leg. That yes. Of course, technical terms are "allowed". Yes, I forgot rotate the ankle.

Answer (score 0):

- Specifically for a face:

  - Molded
  - more specific to expression:

    - grimaced
    - yawned
    - stretched
- For a foot or arm:

  - Flex is fine

> The ones you listed, "flex" and "move", are pretty good choices. Check out "tense" and "extend", although they are different. Also... it is unclear exactly what the question is. Are you looking for one single word that applies to all possible body parts, including the face? Such a word might not exist. (See comments above)

### Recommended:

**CONTORT**: Meaning is similar to flex, but refers more to hyperflexibility and unnatural bodily motions. Applies to all body parts. See https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contort?s=t

Comment: A foot is not generally contorted. One contorts one face or one's body. If your foot is contorted, you probably need an orthopedist. The verbs you propose do not work with feet.

Comment: I've never seen "moulded" for a face movement and would think it sounded odd if it did.  It may be a regional thing (I'm in England).